# Randomness in parallel universes

Tags: quantum-information, universe, randomness, multiverse

Suppose we have two completely identical universes (for instance in Tegmark's type III multiverse). In both of them, two identical men are sitting behind identical random number generators (RAN1 and RAN2), and they push the "search" button at the exact same time.

My question is: will RAN1 and RAN2 generate the same number ?

Comment: If everything were identical, how could they not?

Comment: This is vague. There are lots of ways to generate “random” numbers.

Comment: They are identical till the button is pushed.

Comment: @G.Smith: my question is about any kind of random number generator. Will they generate the same number if they have "identical histories" ?

Comment: This depends on QM interpretation at some level, so can't be answered beyond saying what each would predict

Comment: I would say that a mathematical RNG in a computer will and a physical RNG based on radioactive decay will not.

Comment: Branches in MWI keep branching, if I understand them correctly. Two don’t stay identical.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that by RNG you mean a quantum mechanical random number generator, the two RNGs would only produce the same outputs if they are entangled.  Otherwise the two outputs would be uncorrelated and completely independent.  However, if they are pseudorandom, *deterministic* RNGs typical of the RAN1 and RAN2 RNGs, "completely identical" universes would initiate the RNGs precisely the same way, so would produce precisely the same outputs.

Comment: I'll just explain (for those who don't know) that pseudorandom is not random. It's a formula that will produce random looking output (around the same distribution as random would be expected etc.). (@S. McGrew I know you know, as is evident from the answer. This is for those who don't.)

Comment: Just note that you do not have to be in two different universes to obtain same result from pseudorandom number generators. Simply start the generator with same seed on two different computers in one universe and you will get same series of pseudorandom numbers.